# Grep a title which is inside a HTML source code

Tags: bash

Below is just an example of one of the webpage i have, i have many webpages with the same format. My task is to extract the title information. For this example source code i have below, i need to extract the title which is CA-A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS. I have two locations that i can find this title.

```
<span class="pageHeaderName">CA-A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS</span></h3>

<td valign="top">CA-A CANCER JOURNAL FOR CLINICIANS&nbsp;
```

I am going to use grep to locate this title and store it as a variable ($i) for instance.

Tried using this and didn't work.

```
jtitle=$(grep "<span class="pageHeaderName">" $i | head -n 1 | cut -d'>' -f4- | cut -d'<' -f1
```

Comment: You need to insert the code formatted as code.

Comment: You'll need to grep for $i within the file - `$(grep "$i" <> | head -n 1 | cut -d'>' -f4- | cut -d'<' -f1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear as to how/where you intend to get the title string from. I've the command below to extract the Title from a given html file.

```
jtitle=$(sed -n 's/.*<title>\(.*\)<\/title>.*/\1/ip;T;q' <file.html>)

jtitle=$(awk 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;FS="<title>|</title>";RS=EOF} {print $2}' <file.html>)
```

EDIT : Updated as per the new pattern in the question

```
jtitle=$(sed -n 's/.*<span class="pageHeaderName">\(.*\)<\/span>.*/\1/ip;T;q' <file.html>)
```

Comment: Sorry, the website removed my entire code. i will find a way to put it up. in the meantime, i will look at your codes :)

Comment: Thanks Rahul, you are my hero.... however can you explain to me what does this do? \(.*\)<\/span>.*/\1/ip;T;q'  

Thanks in advance :)